# Layout of Google calendar populated from ical feed

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm populating a number of calendars in Google Calendar via dynamically generated iCalendar feeds. These calendars are being correctly imported into Google Calendar, but their events appear intermixed as shown below:[image: Two calendars being displayed in the Google UI]

Is there a way I can modify the iCal feed to encourage Google to render a single calendar in a single vertical column? It gets confusing when viewing our 12-13 calendars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a way to change this.  The layout is based on the starting time of events, and does not care from where the event was imported.

Although not entirely as per your question, you could change something inconsequential like the seconds of the start date of the event.  For example, all items in your first feed start with the seconds set to :01, all items in your second feed start with the seconds set to :02 etc.  This will not help you when you have an item in the second feed but nothing in the first feed, but should ensure that when you have two items with the same nominal start time the items are ordered correctly in the calendar.